# Sync Data From Hbase To Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

We are working on a project where we are using HBase as operational data store; all data is coming to hbase in real time. And, during every 2 hour, the data in Hbase needs to be synced to Hive. This is to enable analytical queries to run on top of latest data.

For syncing data from Hbase to Hive:

**For insert/update only scenarios**, I can use the timestamp column provided by hbase to know the inserted/updated records. 
**For "DELETE" scenarios**, I am struggling to find the right approach.

Does HBase Scan API provides any option to do that ?

Or should I go with any SQL options like Apache Phoenix for doing the same ?

Comment: You can query Hbase from Hive...

Comment: I hope you are taking about Hive+HBase table, but based on my experience it is not good for analytical use cases (performance wise)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer from HBase Reference Guide, section [Keep Deleted Cells](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#cf.keep.deleted):

> A new "raw" scan options returns all deleted rows and the delete
>   markers...
>
> . . .[example]
>
> hbase(main):017:0> scan 'test', {**RAW=>true**, VERSIONS=>1000}
>
> ROW          COLUMN+CELL
>   r1           column=e:c1, timestamp=14, value=value
>   r1           column=e:c1, timestamp=12, value=value
>   r1           column=e:c1, timestamp=11, **type=DeleteColumn**
>   r1           column=e:c1, timestamp=10, value=value
>
> 1 row(s) in 0.0120 seconds
>
> . . .

Note that there can be different *types* of markers  -- *DeleteColumn* or *DeleteFamily* -- depending on what kind of DELETE has occurred.

Comment: good to hear that rows will be maintained by HBase even after compaction :)